# Grouping by year and month on date stored as a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, aggregate-functions

I have a data set with the following sample information:

```
ID  DTE         CNTR
1   20110102.0  2
1   20110204.0  3
1   20110103.0  5
2   20110205.0  6
2   20110301.0  7
2   20110302.0  3
```

If I want to group the information by month and sum the counter, the code I'm guessing would be this:

```
SELECT t.ID,
,SUM CASE(WHEN t.DTE between 20110101 and 20110131 then t.CNTR else 0) as Jan
,SUM CASE(WHEN t.DTE between 20110201 and 20110228 then t.CNTR else 0) as Feb
,SUM CASE(WHEN t.DTE between 20110301 and 20110331 then t.CNTR else 0) as Mar
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.ID
```

But, is there a way to aggregate that information into another two columns called "month" and "year" and group it that way, leaving me flexibility to preform select queries over many different time periods?

Comment: Is "DTE" a column of type date or of type integer?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' DTE is a type decimal.

Comment: @gsforfree Why are you storing a date as a decimal?

Comment: @bluefeet because that's what the DBA decided?  I'm only a user of the DB, so I take what they give me ;)

Comment: Suggestion: please rename the question to something like "Grouping by date year and month on date in decimal format"

Comment: @gsforfree please explain to your dba that `DATE` is the prefered method for storing dates. It's almost as if the `DATE` datatype was created for that exact purpose.

Comment: [nooooooooooooooo](http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit, since your datatype is a decimal, you can use the following:

```
select ID,
    left(dte, 4) year,
    SUBSTRING(cast(dte as varchar(8)), 5, 2) mth,
    sum(CNTR) Total
from yt
group by id, left(dte, 4), SUBSTRING(cast(dte as varchar(8)), 5, 2)
```

My suggestion would be to use the correct datatype for this which would be datetime. Then if you want the data for each month in columns, then you can use:

```
SELECT t.ID
    , SUM(CASE WHEN t.DTE between '20110101' and '20110131' then t.CNTR else 0 end) as Jan
    , SUM(CASE WHEN t.DTE between '20110201' and '20110228' then t.CNTR else 0 end) as Feb
    , SUM(CASE WHEN t.DTE between '20110301' and '20110331' then t.CNTR else 0 end) as Mar
    , year(dte)
FROM yt t
GROUP BY t.ID, year(dte);
```

This query includes a column to get the year for each `DTE` value.

If you want the result in multiple rows instead of columns, then you can use:

```
select ID,
    YEAR(dte) year,
    datename(m, dte) month,
    sum(CNTR) Total
from yt
group by id, year(dte), datename(m, dte);
```

Note, this assumes that the `DTE` is a date datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea - using div/modulo operators:

```
select (dte / 10000) dte_year, ((dte % 10000) / 100) dte_month,sum(cntr) 
from tablename
group by (dte / 10000) , ((dte % 10000) / 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select    id,
          datepart(yy, convert(datetime, dte, 112)),
          datepart(mm, convert(datetime, dte, 112)),
          sum(cntr)
from      table 
group by  id,
          datepart(yy, convert(datetime, dte, 112)),
          datepart(mm, convert(datetime, dte, 112))
```

Comment: i came up with something like that:

`YEAR(CONVERT (DATETIME, CONVERT (VARCHAR (8), [t].[DTE]))) AS CAP_YR`  Is this more expensive than your solution?